# App crashes when On onActivityResult with Galaxy S4

Tags: android, camera

I have an activity that takes a picture and then set an imageview with the image that was captured, and then uploads it to parse.
It works perfectly fine with LG G4, but with galaxy S4 it crashes after I press the button that says that I want this picture, it crashes in the OnActivityResult function.
I see in the log that there is a nullpointerexception, I guess because galaxy s4 has less memory then LG G4.
I think I understand the problem(my assumption about the memory), but have no clue how to tackle it.

The activity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.GetDataCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class SituationStatusActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imVCature_pic_nir;
    ImageView imVCature_pic_sharon;

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    String imageFilePath;
    public SharedPreferences startExplePref;
    public String user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_situation_status);
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            imageFilePath = savedInstanceState.getString("path");
        }
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

//       get the user
        startExplePref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        user = startExplePref.getString("user", "");
//        upload nir Pic

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        imageFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Android/data/com.my.app/Image-" + timeStamp + ".png";

        imVCature_pic_nir = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nirPic);
        imVCature_pic_sharon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sharonPic);

        Button uploadPic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.picUploadButton);
        uploadPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {    /*************************** Camera Intent Start ************************/
                File imageFile = new File(imageFilePath);
                Uri imageFileUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile); // convert path to Uri
                // Standard Intent action that can be sent to have the camera
                // application capture an image and return it.
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFileUri);   // set the image file name
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                /*************************** Camera Intent End ************************/
            }
        });

        UpdatePic();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        outState.putString("path", imageFilePath);

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
// if picture was taken
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = 5;
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

            //imageFilePath image path which you pass with intent
            Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath, bmpFactoryOptions);

            //rotate image by 90 degrees
            Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
            rotateMatrix.postRotate(90);
            Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bp, 0, 0, bp.getWidth(), bp.getHeight(), rotateMatrix, false);
//
            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(rotatedBitmap);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//            // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
            rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
//
//            // Create the ParseFile
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile("image.png", image);
//            // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
            file.saveInBackground();
//
//            // Create a New Class called "ImageUpload" in Parse
            ParseObject SituationPic = new ParseObject("SituationPic");
//
//            // Create a column named "ImageName" and set the string
            SituationPic.put("ImageName", "First Pic");
//
            SituationPic.put("user", user);

//            // Create a column named "ImageFile" and insert the image
            SituationPic.put("ImageFile", file);
//
//            // Create the class and the columns
            SituationPic.saveInBackground();

            if (user.equals("nir")) {
                imVCature_pic_nir.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(rotatedBitmap, 500));
                imVCature_pic_nir.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

            } else if (user.equals("sharon")) {
                imVCature_pic_sharon.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(rotatedBitmap, 500));
                imVCature_pic_sharon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(SituationStatusActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

//       if picture was not taken
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
//        UpdatePic();
    }


    public Bitmap nirBitmap;
    public Bitmap sharonBitmap;
    //change it to load in the beginiing
    public void UpdatePic()
    {
//        Update photo of nir
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> querynir = ParseQuery.getQuery("SituationPic");
        querynir.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
        querynir.whereEqualTo("user", "nir");
        querynir.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                ParseObject object = objects.get(0);
                ParseFile applicantResume = (ParseFile) object.get("ImageFile");
                applicantResume.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                                    data.length);
                            Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
                            rotateMatrix.postRotate(360);
                            Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), rotateMatrix, false);
                            nirBitmap = rotatedBitmap;
                            imVCature_pic_nir.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(rotatedBitmap, 500));
                            imVCature_pic_nir.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        //        Update photo of sharon
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> querySHN = ParseQuery.getQuery("SituationPic");
        querySHN.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
        querySHN.whereEqualTo("user", "sharon");
        querySHN.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                ParseObject object = objects.get(0);

                ParseFile applicantResume = (ParseFile) object.get("ImageFile");
                applicantResume.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                                    data.length);
                            Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
                            rotateMatrix.postRotate(180);
                            Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), rotateMatrix, false);

                            sharonBitmap = rotatedBitmap;


                            imVCature_pic_sharon.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(rotatedBitmap, 500));
                            imVCature_pic_sharon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

    public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
                .getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = pixels;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }


}
```

The LogCat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: fastner.israel.nir_zabari.onelove, PID: 31324
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {fastner.israel.nir_zabari.onelove/fastner.israel.nir_zabari.onelove.SituationStatusActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {fastner.israel.nir_zabari.onelove/fastner.israel.nir_zabari.onelove.SituationStatusActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3394)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3425)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2763)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4462)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1454)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {fastner.israel.nir_zabari.onelove/fastner.israel.nir_zabari.onelove.SituationStatusActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4058)                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3380)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3425) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2763) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4462) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1454) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at fastner.israel.nir_zabari.onelove.SituationStatusActivity.onActivityResult(SituationStatusActivity.java:117)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6549)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4054)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3380) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3425) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2763) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4462) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1454) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before doing any work with decoded bitmap you need to check it is actually decoded well.

```
// Code above
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new mapFactory.Options();
    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = 5;
    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    //imageFilePath image path which you pass with intent
    Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath, bmpFactoryOptions);
    if (bp != null) {
        //rotate image by 90 degrees
        Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
        rotateMatrix.postRotate(90);
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bp, 0, 0, bp.getWidth(), bp.getHeight(), rotateMatrix, false);
    }
// Code below
```